# Using reduce with async and wait

Tags: node.js, typescript, asynchronous, promise

I'm aware that other post cover this subject BUT I need to use it as `const` so that it's init at runtime only

Here is my issue, I'm new to nodejs and searched this a lot on the web. Didn't find any solution close to my need

```
const apis = ['log', 'get', 'all']

const loggers = apis.reduce(async (memo, api) => {
  try {
    await fs.stat(path.join(process.cwd() + config.application.log.dir, api));
  } catch (e) {
    await fs.mkdir(path.join(process.cwd() + config.application.log.dir, api));
  }
  memo[api] = new (winston.Logger)({
    transports: [
      new winston.transports.File({
        timestamp: () => (new Date().toLocaleTimeString()),
        datePattern: 'yyyy-MM-dd',
        level: config.application.mode === 'test' ? 'emerg' : 'info',
        filename: path.join(process.cwd(), config.application.log.dir, api, `${api}.log`),
        maxsize: 1024 * 1024 * 100, // 100MB
        colorize: false,
        prepend: true,
        json: false,
      }),
    ],
  });
  return await Promise.resolve(memo);
}, {});
```

My issue is that the results are Promises any idea how to change that ?

EDIT : -----------------------

I finally opted for this solution, and call it from app.ts during express initialization (if you have a better idea don't hesitate to add it):

```
export const loggerInitialisation = async function (): Promise<void> {

  // Create all log folders
  await Promise.all(apis.map(async (api) => {
    try {
      await fs.stat(path.join(process.cwd() + config.application.log.dir, api));
    } catch (e) {
      await fs.mkdir(path.join(process.cwd() + config.application.log.dir, api));
    }
  }));
  // Create for each log folder a winston logger and transport
  loggers = apis.reduce((memo, api) => {
    memo[api] = new (winston.Logger)({
      transports: [
        new winston.transports.File({
          timestamp: () => (new Date().toLocaleTimeString()),
          datePattern: 'yyyy-MM-dd',
          level: config.application.mode === 'test' ? 'emerg' : 'info',
          filename: path.join(process.cwd(), config.application.log.dir, api, `${api}.log`),
          maxsize: 1024 * 1024 * 100, // 100MB
          colorize: false,
          prepend: true,
          json: false,
        }),
      ],
    });
    return memo;
  }, {});
};
```

Comment: The results always will be promises - the functions will always be asynchronous (that's what the `async` means). There's no way around this than to wait for your `loggers` before using them.

Comment: `fs.stat` and `fs.mkdir` don't return promises, so you can't `await` them (in a meaningful manner).